# c# Add variable to list in a specific index

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, addition

I wonder how you can add a variable to a specific list index. Let me give an example..

```
int a = 4;
List<int> listB = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
     if (a == i)
     {
          listB.(something like add to index, this is the part I dont know what to do, my guess would be listB.AddToIndex(a, a) for adding variable a to index a in the list.)
     }
}
```

I hope I explained understandable, thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Insert function:

```
listB.Insert(a, item);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Insert()` method on `List<T>` is exactly for this purpose

If you want to insert at 1st index

```
  listB.Insert(1, someValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

you  can use  this

```
         listB.Insert(a,a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `listB.Add(item)` to add an item at the end of the list.

Use `listB.Insert(index, item)` to choose where the item will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The `Insert(index, item)` method allows you to do this.